# weird behavior of javascript objects when assigning a value to it

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I want to understand this concept which confuses me.

suppose I have the below logic:

```
function test(){
    var jsonObj_1 = {};
    var jsonObj_2 = {};
    
    jsonObj_2 = jsonObj_1;
    jsonObj_2.myKey = 3;

    console.log(jsonObj_2) // result => {myKey:3}
    console.log(jsonObj_1) // result => {myKey:3}

}
```

my question is why `jsonObj_1` is equal to  `{myKey:3}` when it's never get assigned?!

Comment: Objects are represented as *references*. When you assign an object value to another variable, you **do not** make a copy of the object: you assign a shared reference to the same object.

Comment: @Pointy Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript Objects are Mutable. They are addressed by reference, not by value.

If jsonObj_1 is an object, the following statement will not create a copy of jsonObj_1:

```js
var jsonObj_2 = jsonObj_1 ;  // This will not create a copy of jsonObj_1.
```

The object jsonObj_2  is not a copy of jsonObj_1 . It is jsonObj_1. Both jsonObj_2 and jsonObj_1 are the same object.

Any changes to jsonObj_2 will also change jsonObj_1, because jsonObj_2 and jsonObj_1 are the same object.

Answer (score 5):

you are assigning the ref of jsonObj_1 in jsonObj_2. In simple words the address of the first variable. I would suggest you to read some docs on call by reference and call by value.

Answer (score 1):

What you will need is `Object.assign`

```
const target = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const source = { b: 4, c: 5 };

const returnedTarget = Object.assign(target, source);

console.log(target);
// expected output: Object { a: 1, b: 4, c: 5 }

console.log(returnedTarget);
// expected output: Object { a: 1, b: 4, c: 5 }
```

Example here:
https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/object-assign-es6/

Answer (score 1):

When the non-primitive variables are assigned using "=", the reference will also be copied. This may lead to the mutation for all the variables that a particular object is assigned to.

Try the following.

You can use JSON.stringify to convert it to string and then parse into JSON.parse.

```
jsonObj_2= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonObj_1));
```

You can use spread operator.

```
jsonObj_2 = {...jsonObj_1}
```